# Why does my gas oven trip the GFCI when turned on after the clean cycle?

Tags: electrical, gas, stove

Maytag MGS5770ADW sn 27787501ZZ

After we run oven clean cycle, GFI outlet trips when oven is turned on. 
This continues for several days and then problem goes away until next time oven is cleaned.

I recently replaced the igniter transformer for the stove top and one of the igniters for the  oven for other reasons. This has made no difference with the GFI tripping following the cleaning cycle.

Comment: I wonder if it's typical that an oven is connected to GFCI-protected circuit.

Comment: Is the oven actually clean?  After the cleaning cycle do you manually clean material out of the oven?  Do you use liquids of any kind when you do?

Comment: Is the GFCI outlet right behind the range and perhaps getting overheated?

Comment: contact  Maytag.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect a small, varying current leakage to the metal frame.  Depending on how your kitchen is wired you might could replace all counter top outlets to GFCI protection, then remove the GFCI protection from the oven granted it is behind the oven amd not readily accessible.  However, doing so may allow a potential shock hazard.

The best option is to have the oven checked out or replaced.

Also, I'd recommend putting the GFCI in the panel if possible or another readily accessible location if the one for the oven is not.

Comment: Removing a GFCI protection on a device that has a small current leak to the frame seems very risky to me. When this leak become larger, say after next cleaning, you might well shock the cleaner with 20 amps without the breaker even triggering. When a device trigger the GFCI, check the device, don't remove the GFCI.

Comment: That is a good point.  And worth mentioning in my answer.